# django error 'too many values to unpack'

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm learning Django by building a simple recipes app. I have a 1 table model using the 'choices' field option for recipe categories rather than using a 2nd 'categories' table and a foreign key relationship. So i created db table via syncdb and then loaded table with test data. When i go to admin and click on the 'Recipes' link in an attempt to view recipes i get the following error:

```
Template error

In template /var/lib/python-support/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 34
Caught an exception while rendering: too many values to unpack
```

If anyone can shed light on this cryptic error that would be great. Db is Sqlite. Django version is 1.0. The model is listed below:

```
from django.db import models

class Recipe(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (1, u'Appetizer'),
        (2, u'Bread'),
        (3, u'Dessert'),
        (4, u'Drinks'),
        (5, u'Main Course'),
        (6, u'Salad'),
        (7, u'Side Dish'),
        (8, u'Soup'),
        (9, u'Sauce/Marinade'),
        (10, u'Other'),        
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    ingredients = models.TextField()
    directions = models.TextField()
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Unless, there's a bug in the Django dev version, this doesn't look problematic. Any chance you have custom admin templates or ModelAdmin definitions somewhere?

Answer (score 22):

**Edit: Updated in light of kibibu's correction.**

I have encountered what I believe is this same error, producing the message:

```
Caught ValueError while rendering: too many values to unpack
```

My form class was as follows:

```
class CalcForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('17815', '17816')))
```

Note that my `choices` type here a tuple. Django official documentation reads as follows for the `choices` arg:

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for
>   this field. This argument accepts the same formats as the choices
>   argument to a model field.

src: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices

This problem was solved by my observing the documentation and using a **list of tuples:**

```
class CalcForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('17815', '17816')])
```

Do note that while the docs state any iterable of the correct form can be used, a tuple of 2-tuples did not work:

```
item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('17815', '17816'), ('123', '456')))
```

This produced the same error as before.

Lesson: bugs happen.

Comment: List of tuples works for me too. choises=[('a_val','a'),('b_val','b')]. Thanks!

Comment: `item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('17815', '17816')))` is NOT a tuple of tuples. It is a tuple in parentheses. You need to do `item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('17815', '17816'),))`. Note the comma.

Of course, your second example is the correct format and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `ChoiceField` instead of `SmallIntegerField`

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it's because whatever is in the administrative template expects a list of tuples, but you've instead supplied a tuple of tuples (hence the "too many values"). Try replacing with a list instead:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [    # Note square brackets.
    (1, u'Appetizer'),
    (2, u'Bread'),
    (3, u'Dessert'),
    (4, u'Drinks'),
    (5, u'Main Course'),
    (6, u'Salad'),
    (7, u'Side Dish'),
    (8, u'Soup'),
    (9, u'Sauce/Marinade'),
    (10, u'Other'),        
]
```

Comment: Django's choices can be any iterable (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices), not just a "list or a tuple", so this isn't likely it, even though it's a good thought.

Answer (score 1):

Per http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/972 , you need to move the assignment `CATEGORY_CHOICES = ...` *outside* the `class` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Most of the 'too many values to unpack' errors that i came across while googling were Value Error types. My error was a Template Syntax type. To load my recipe table i had imported a csv file. I was thinking maybe there was a problem somewhere in the data that sqlite allowed on import. So i deleted all data and then added 2 recipes manually via django admin form. The list of recipes loaded after that.

thanks.

Comment: I have to say, this isn't a terribly satisfying answer. I'd be more interested in knowing how to fix the problem (and thus what it was), not a workaround. After all, what happens if it occurs again? But I'm glad you were able to find a solution that worked for you.

Comment: Here I had the same problem: "too many values to unpack"
I looked to the exception stack and found out that the problem occurred on a "split" operation on a timestamp. The timestamp was bad encoded because the data was inserted directly in the sqlite shell.

The message django gives us isn't a good clue about the real problem, just it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem... my cvs file came from ms excel and the date fields gotten the wrong format at saving time. I change the format to something like '2010-05-04 13:05:46.790454'  (excel gave me 5/5/2010  10:05:47) and voilaaaa no more 'too many values to unpack’

Answer (score 0):

kibibu's comment to Kreychek's answer is correct. This isn't a Django issue but rather an interesting aspect of Python. To summarize:

In Python, round parentheses are used for both order of operations and tuples. So:

```
foo = (2+2)
```

will result in foo being 4, not a tuple who's first and only element is 4: 4

```
foo = (2+2, 3+3)
```

will result in foo being a two-dimensional tuple: (4,6)

To tell Python that you want to create a one-dimensional tuple instead of just denoting the order of operations, use a trailing comma:

```
foo = (2+2,)
```

will result in foo being a one-dimensional tuple who's first and only element is 4: (4,)

So for your scenario:

```
class CalcForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('17815', '17816'),))
```

would give what you want. Using a list is a great solution too (more Pythonic in my opinion), but hopefully this answer is informative since this can come up in other cases.

For example:

```
print("foo: %s" % (foo))
```

may give an error if foo is an iterable, but:

```
print("foo: %s" % (foo,))
```

or:

```
print("foo: %s" % [foo])
```

will properly convert foo to a string whether it's an iterable or not.

Documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: In regards to it being more Pythonic, no, not really. A tuple is immutable; it cannot be changed once created. A list of choices should typically be unchanged, which is why a tuple is suggested.

Comment: By more Pythonic, in this case, I mean more readable. `forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('17815', '17816'),))` has a lot of brackets and it can get confusing what's a tuple and what's a function call. By using a list instead of a tuple, it's more obvious: `forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('17815', '17816')])`. You're right about the differences between a tuple and a list but I think we can trust Django to not change the list here. In fact, it's docs explicitly say any iterable is allowed and show an example with a list: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

Answer (score 0):

This error IMO occurs when a function returns three values, and you assign it to 2. e.g.:

```
def test():
    a=0
    b=0
    c=0
.... 
a,b=test() <---three values returned, but only assigning to 2.
```

a,b,c=test() <---three values returned, assigned to 3.OK