# I'm getting an error that I do not understand from Django

Tags: django

I am trying to follow [James Bennett](https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/)
 example but getting this error:

```
ValueError at /loadtest
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/loadtest
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Exception Location: /Users/lowell.dennis/Code/loadtest/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py, line 691, in _choice_has_empty_value
Python Executable:  /Users/lowell.dennis/Code/loadtest/env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.6
Python Path:    
['/Users/lowell.dennis/Code/loadtest',
 '/Users/lowell.dennis/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/lowell.dennis/Code/loadtest/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 24 Jul 2021 01:52:04 +0000
```

I am hoping that someone can see the error I am making.

Here is my form class code code:

```
class DynamicForm(Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    dynamic = kwargs.pop('dynamic', 0)
    super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in dynamic:
      self.fields[field[0]] = field[1]
```

I am building an array of tuples, (name, field), where name is the name of the field and field is the field type (like CharField, ChoiceField, FloatField, IntegerField, URLField) with the prompt, initial, label, required and where needed choices items filled in).

My view function ends with this:

```
 return render(request, 'loadtest.html', {'form': DynamicForm(dynamic = fields)})
```

My loadtest.html contains the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    {{ form.as_table}}
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.
I discovered that I could get rid of this error if I removed all of my ChoiceFields.  Clearly, I was not handling them correctly.

Originally, I had seen an example that showed choices to look something like this:

```
choice = ( ('Choice1', 'Choice1'), (Choice2, Choice2) )
```

Then I saw this [stack overflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913590/django-error-too-many-values-to-unpack/8206621) and found out you have to use a list of tuples and not a tuple of tuples.

```
choice = [ ('Choice1', 'Choice1'), ('Choice2', 'Choice2') ]
```